# A valid JSON, which on parse should result in a list of strings

Tags: json

I am using this rest api: https://www.hackerrank.com/api/docs to run code. here test case should be:

```
A valid JSON, which on parse should result in a list of strings.
```

And my code is:

```
 $sourceCode = urldecode($_POST['sourceCode']);
  $testCases = '["20","50"]'; //$_POST['testcases'];

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'source='.$sourceCode.'&lang=2&testcases='.$testCases.'&api_key=hackerrank|****************');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Is the following  *A valid JSON, which on parse should result in a list of strings.*:

```
  $testCases = '["20","50"]';
```

?

Comment: You should probably obfuscate your api_key in your sample, unless you're ok with random people from the internet using it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid json for a list of strings:

```
[
  "50",
  "25"
]
```

This is a valid string representing a json for a list of strings:

```
'["50","25"]';
```

The short answer is **A valid JSON, which on parse should result in a list of strings**. I think you need to pass a json object to the api, not a string containing a json object, but I can't tell with certainty.

Here you have a json parser: http://json.parser.online.fr/